# Rsaga geoprocessor (Shapes to grid)

Tags: r, gis

I am trying to export a raster file using "shapes to grid" function in R, using the RSAGA package.

The script, made so far, is the following:

```
rsaga.geoprocessor("grid_gridding", module = 0,
                                param = list(
                                  GRID = paste(getwd(),"/SIG/Mapas/rasterpre", sep = ""),
                                  INPUT = paste(getwd(),"/SIG/Mapas/","CoordDatosDisco.shp", sep = ""),
                                  FIELD = 0,
                                  TARGET_TYPE = 0,
                                  USER_CELL_SIZE = 0.01,
                                  USER_FIT_EXTENT = TRUE,
                                  USER_X_EXTENT_MIN =  -77,
                                  USER_X_EXTENT_MAX =  -65,
                                  USER_Y_EXTENT_MIN =  -57,
                                  USER_Y_EXTENT_MAX =  -17,
                                  USER_GRID_TYPE = 3
                                  ))
```

The input is a point shapefile containing data and long/lat information. However, when I want to open the output file (rasterpre) in SAGA - GIS (using the GDAL:import raster module) the software warns me with the following message : "Module execution failed".

Does anyone know which could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Héctor M.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs it, I solved the problem by updating saga gis to 2.1.0 version ( I was using 2.0.4 version).

Regards

H